# Lags in multiple layouts RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, facebook-audience-network

I have the `RecyclerView` with 2 layouts. The first one describes main item and the second is `facebook` `native Ad`. It works, but every time the `position` with `NativeViewAd` is be shown on the display  - we can see micro-lags.

`recycler_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:id="@+id/list_item">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/food_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/blank2" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/test_name_food"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#242424"
            android:paddingTop="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingr_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_name_ingr"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <!--
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="33">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ic_ingredient"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_ingredient"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ic_time"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        -->



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/look"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Просмотреть"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#4CAF50"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and `additional.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/ad_test2"
android:background="@drawable/blank2">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/blank2"
    android:id="@+id/blank_holder"/>
```

Here's a gist of `RecyclerAdapter.class` https://gist.github.com/burnix/d0b32f0dc4b525ec3aa7 if you need, but I suppose, that there is a problem in the one of `layouts`.

So how can I solve my issue?

P.S. If `layouts` even have the same `height`,  lags don't  disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very  upset  about Stackoverflow. Seems, that only  pre-juniors are surfing here  for  answering  questions  like:"why I have NPE in onClick?"...

Here is solution. Hope it would be useful:
 To solve lags in Recycler:
In adapter:

```
   Picasso.with(context)
          .load(...)
          .tag("resume_tag")
          .into(...);
```

In  `EndlessScrollListener` class

```
   @Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    final Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        picasso.resumeTag("resume_tag");
    } else {
        picasso.pauseTag("resume_tag");
    }

}
```

In the  class, that calls RecyclerView:

```
    if (offset == 0)
                            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, foodDataList.size());  //or adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        else
                            adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(foodDataList.size() - jsonArray.length(), foodDataList.size());
```

Comment: Hi @peter! Great answer, the first half of the answer certainly reduced the lag to some extent and for even better performance I changed Picasso's config to `RGB_565` which reduces the image quality to 2 bytes/pixel instead of the default 4 bytes/pixel. (this config is used by Glide - the image processing library recommended by Google).

Also, I quite didn't get the second part of your answer. Which offset are you talking about here? Can you please elaborate on this.